# Convert a string to a number in console.log

Tags: javascript

I want the use to input the users age and send it to a new variable that adds + 10 to the age and write it outin the console.log.

```js
let age = prompt("Whats youre age ?")
age1=  age + 10;
console.log(age1)
```

If I type in users input age=10 the output in the console log is = 1010.
I want it to type out = 20.

I need to convert it to a number with parseInt ? but how ?

Comment: [MDN parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+prompt+number+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You say yourself you want to use parseInt.
What went wrong?

```js
let age = prompt("Whats youre age ?")

let age1 =  parseInt(age) + 10;

console.log(age1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works !  I understand that i need to convert it like parseInt but I didn´t know  how and where to type it the code . Thank you again problem solved.